# Neo4J's APOC plugin (3.1.3.6) is running very slow

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I recently upgraded my Neo4j to 3.1.3, and alongside that, got the most recent APOC plugin (3.1.3.6).

I had a bit of code that worked fine, and could create ~3 million relationships in about a minute and a half wall time.  But now, it's been running for over 8 hours and shows no sign of stopping...

Because the code *used to* run without any problems, I'm hoping something must have changed between versions that has lead to my code having been borked.

Is it `rock_n_roll` that should be changed (maybe to `apoc.periodic.commit` with positional arguments or something)? Thanks for any insight.

Here's what I'm running .

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
  "MATCH (c:ChessPlayer),(r:Record) WHERE c.ChessPlayer_ID = r.ChessPlayer RETURN c,r",
  "CYPHER planner=rule WITH {c} AS c, {r} AS r CREATE (c)-[:HAD_RECORD]->(r)",
  200000)
```

Comment: What versions of neo4j and apoc were you using previously?

Comment: Hi cybersam! I know I was running `neo4j-community-3.0.1` but I'm not sure what version of apoc I had :/

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that call is querying the Cartesian product of ChessPlayers and Records, and then trying to filter them out row by row, and then doing the batch update on those final results (which eats a lot of memory, I think this one opening transaction is what's killing you). So if you can break it up so that each transaction can touch as few nodes as possible, it should be able to perform massively better (especially if r.ChessPlayer is indexed, since now you don't need to load all of them)

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
  "MATCH (c:ChessPlayer) WHERE NOT EXISTS((c)-[:HAD_RECORD]->()) RETURN c",
  "MATCH (r:Record) WHERE c.ChessPlayer_ID = r.ChessPlayer WITH c,r CREATE UNIQUE (c)-[:HAD_RECORD]->(r)",
  100000)
```

periodic.commit() would work on a similar principle. The smaller (least nodes touched) you can make each transaction, the faster the batch will become.